# how to change desc to asc order in haygeek upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Haygeek Upload](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#sequential)

I'm using haygeek upload plugins for file upload now what is my question is [image: Upload Pix]

while im uploading like below file is showing in desc order how can i change it asc order in this plugin ?

```
1. Filename progressbar 
2. Filename progressbar 
3. Filename progressbar
```

***Jquery***

```
$("#sequentialupload").uploadFile({
url:"upload.php",
fileName:"myfile",
sequential:true,
sequentialCount:1   
});
```

***Html***

```
<div id="sequentialupload"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In documentation I cannot find any options for sort (maybe docs is deprecated), but in plugin source I found this code:

```
if(s.uploadQueuOrder == 'bottom')
                $(obj.container).append(bar.statusbar);
            else
                $(obj.container).prepend(bar.statusbar);
```

By default `uploadQueuOrder` property is set to `top`. Just change it to `bottom`

So you code must be like this

```
$("#sequentialupload").uploadFile({
    url:"upload.php",
    fileName:"myfile",
    sequential:true,
    sequentialCount:1,
    uploadQueuOrder: 'bottom'
});
```

Comment: where i need to use this  `uploadQueuOrder ` ?

Comment: You should pass `uploadQueuOrder` like an option in plugin init. Please see last code example in my answer.

Comment: yes i saw that but i need to use in plugin source ?

Comment: No no no, only in initialization

Comment: i dont know how to use this

Comment: You only need to add `uploadQueuOrder: 'bottom'` to your jquery code

Comment: `if(s.uploadQueuOrder == 'bottom')
                $(obj.container).append(bar.statusbar);
            else
                $(obj.container).prepend(bar.statusbar);` where to add this one ?

Comment: No, don't look at this code. It is from plugin. Just use an option that I described in comments.